# Validar login con JavaScript y ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, funciones, validación, function

lo que pasa es que he estado intentando hacer una validacion de un login pero solo validando la contraseña ya que no es necesario que use el usuario. Todo lo estoy haciendo por el lado del cliente con javascript en ASP.NET pero como soy nuevo en javascript no tengo la certera idea de como lograr esta validacion.
Bueno, lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que al momento que el cliente clickee en un boton la pagina te mande un PROMPT de javascript y luego ahi en ese PROMPT escribir la contraseña y entonces hacer la validacion, asi esta mi funcion actualmente.

ASP.NET

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                      <ItemTemplate>                          
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="AddButton" OnClientClick="return validate();" runat="server" Height="15" ImageUrl="images/der_up.png"
                          CommandName="Actualizar" CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>" />                        
                      </ItemTemplate> 
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Javascript

```
function validate()
        {

            var password = prompt("Introduzca su contraseña: ");

            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

            if (password == "") {
                alert("Introduzca su contraseña!")

                return false
            }

            if (password == "123") {
                alert("Contraseña correcta");

                return false;
            }

            else {
                alert("Contraseña incorrecta, intente de nuevo")
            }


            }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente lo que te sobra para que funcione tu código es la segunda asignación que haces a la variable `password` desde un elemento con id `password`.

```js
document.getElementById('AddButton').addEventListener('click', validate);

function validate()
{
    var password = prompt("Introduzca su contraseña: ");
    if (password == "") {
        alert("Introduzca su contraseña!")
        return false
    }
    if (password == "123") {
        alert("Contraseña correcta");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("Contraseña incorrecta, intente de nuevo");
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="AddButton">Validar</button>
```

En cualquier caso tu planteamiento tiene varios problemas.

No deberías usar `prompt` y `alert` salvo para pruebas en tus desarrollos. Los navegadores actuales permiten bloquear este tipo de ventanas y es muy posible que algunos de tus usuarios no puedan verlas.

Y sobre todo: una validación así nunca se debería hacer en javascript. Una validación en javascript es sencillísima de saltar por lo que nunca deberías fiarte de ellas. Las validaciones en cliente son únicamente útiles para mejorar la experiencia del usuario pero no para comprobar que los datos sean correctos.

Ya sé que sólo es un ejemplo simple pero, en tu caso, bastaría con mirar el código javascript con las Herramientas de Desarrollo del navegador para ver que la contraseña es "123".

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado correctamente.

Comment: En cuanto a lo que me dijo, me pidieron que hiciera la validacion usando un popup entonces lo unico que encontre fue el PROMPT con javascript y no encontre otra alternativa. Sobre lo de la contraseña en realidad lo que tengo que hacer es validarla y ademas es traida de una base de datos (SQL Server en este caso) pero no se aun como hacer eso y por eso voy por pasos, gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Pero la contraseña de base de datos no deberías mandarla nunca a cliente (al código javascript). Lo que deberías hacer es mandar el valor introducido por el usuario a servidor y comprobar allí (en tu código ASP.NET) si el valor del usuario es correcto.

Comment: Bueno, olvide sobre eso, la verdad en un principio quería hacer eso, pero vi que era más fácil hacerlo en el lado del cliente así que me incline por hacer la validación ahí. Le tengo una pregunta, de ser así entonces ¿lo que tengo que hacer es tomar el valor introducido por el cliente en el prompt usando javascript y entonces mandarlo al backend usando también javascript? Estoy usando Visual Basic.

Comment: Veo que utilizas WebForms, la forma más sencilla sería incluir un control `HiddenField` en el que almacenar el valor. De esta forma lo tendrías como valor del control al hacer PostBack. En cualquier caso te recomendaría buscar información sobre Modal Popups en WebForms (haz una búsqueda en Google y tendrás muchos ejemplos) para evitar el prompt. Trata de ir por ahí y, si te surgen problemas, abre una nueva pregunta para evitar chats en los comentarios.